# Flutter TextField issue in Samsung S21

Tags: flutter, textfield, samsung-mobile

I have a weird experience on a certain Samsung mobile. After I removed every design elements and simplified the issue the problem still exist. In normal case (emulator or another phone) the result is this:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKJZ8.png)]

But a certain Samsung mobile the Textfield cover the whole screen, doesn't matter what I do, its created a big grey square:
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDES9.png)]

And I have no idea what can I do on this mobile. I need a text input field. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:masters/main_web.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
   if (kIsWeb) {
    runApp(const MyWebApp());
  } else {
    runApp(SkillLinkApp());
  }
}

class SkillLinkApp extends StatelessWidget {
  SkillLinkApp({super.key});
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _emailController.text = "v21";
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Verseny nevezés",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
        supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
          Locale('en'),
          Locale('hu'),
        ],
        home: Scaffold(
          body: TextField(
              controller: _emailController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              onChanged: null,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        )
        );
  }
}
```

The Samsung mobile data:
Samsun Galaxy S21 5G  (SM-G991B/DS). Android version: 13, One UI-version 5.1.

Anybody has any idea?
Thanks

I could test on S21, it was good, but it has Android 12.
I could test with Android 13 on another phone, it was also good.

Comment: Did you run it on debug or release mode?

Comment: Debug mode on the emulator. But I have deployed to Play Store to test on that Samsung mobile (it is in another country).

Comment: I asked this question in Flutter community, and finally I got answer. I should put the
              localizationsDelegates: const [
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
              ],
to the main.dart
I don't know why, but it helped to solve  this strange issue.